# C# ListView Design

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview

I want to make program that gets the news using [NewsApi](https://newsapi.org/) and want to display them in the program but i can't display them as i want. I can display the results like in the first image.

[First Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFlUG.png)

But i want to display the results like in the second image.

[Second Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gfBeU.png)

The NewsApi returns the headline,description, image link, date etc.
So how can i display the result like in the second image. Should i use list view or is there anything else i can use the display as i want.

Comment: It's probably simpler to use a HTML template and use a WebBrowser control to show the html page when filled. You'll have no problems with the links as well. A ListView can show similar results, but you'll lose some functionality, as the ability to click a link. Well, you could use a LinkLabel, but... UserControls shown in a FlowLayoutPanel is probably easier to handle (provided that you dispose of these controls correctly).

Comment: ListViewItems will have the same height, even if you use LargeImage and owner-draw the items. UserControls shown in a FlowLayoutPanel as Jimi suggest will be the easiest and most flexible solution..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A short mistake out there.

Instead of using listbox, use a TableLayoutPanel or a FlowLayoutPanel.
(More documentation for TableLayoutPanel here : [C# TableLayout](https://coding-examples.com/csharp/c-tablelayoutpanel-example/))

That way you can add images too on the left side with the news. It will get you a result exactly as shown in the second image.

This could be of some help to use a FlowLayoutPanel : [Scrolling FlowLayoutPanel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DJX6WgvOgk0)

Comment: @ugurinal: Hope my answer answers your question!! Feel free to ask for any help.

Answer (score -1):

If you know .Net Mvc,you can use HTML table and entity framework.It will easy for this work.But still you want work with ListView you must learn sizing image etc.